# How do I set affinity of a particular thread on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, thread

I'm trying to figure out how to set the affinity of a particular thread (but not the entire process) on a FreeBSD system.

On Linux, I'm able to do this with `ps -L uH [pid]`, obtaining the LWP ID of the thread, and then using `taskset` as I would with an actual PID - `taskset -pc [cpu list] [lwp]`. I haven't been able to find a similar method for FreeBSD.

I'm able to get a thread ID with `procstat -t [pid]`, but attempting to set the affinity on that (with `cpuset -l [cpu list] -p [thread id]`) returns "no such process."

Comment: Add -S to procstat to see which cpusets the thread belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

According to the manpage there's an option `-t` to cpuset for specifying threads (`-p` only takes PID's):

```
-t tid    Specifies a thread id as the target of the operation.
```

I don't have a FreeBSD system right now to test so I don't know if you need to specify `-p` or if `-t` is good enough. You may try without then with and observe the results.